# Picture not saving to gallery Android Studio

Tags: android

**manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Consultartlista"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Agregarpersonaje" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>

</application>
```

**Activity:**

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Consultartlista.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Consultartlista.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Consultartlista.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1000);
        }        

String currentPhotoPath;

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

private void tomarFoto() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
          Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}


    @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.agregarimg:
            tomarFoto();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);

    }

}

    @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater2 = getMenuInflater();
    inflater2.inflate(R.menu.menuopcionesimg,menu);

}
```

AND i will leave a pic of the pathfiles cuz idk why stackoverflow doesnt allow me paste that.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKwhJ.png

im trying to click (short) an item from a lis view, get a context menu with an option to "add img" i click on that and camera starts. i take the photo but no image on the device storage. i tried test it on my physic phone and the same, no "new" image on the gallery. whats wrong?

Comment: There are few storage related changes from Android 10 onwards. Do have a look : https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/storage

Comment: `// Error occurred while creating the File` But you do not display a Toast to inform the user. And you continue as if nothing had happened. You should return then. You did not post the code that tried to create a file but did not.

Comment: @SumitSahoo im on android 9. should apply that anyway or not?

Comment: @blackapps i added that toast and nothing change, still all the same.

Comment: I dont see that toast code.

Comment: @blackapps im saying after read ur reply, i wrote it on that line, and compile and was the same thing. Nothing happends.

Comment: If you dont update your code nothing happens here too.

Comment: @Kondos yes if you are using SDK 29 to develop then you need to. Else change compile SDK to 28.

Comment: @SumitSahoo how i can check my SDK version? ALSO: i realized that now (idk how) the pictures are saving, BUT!! i went to sleep last night and no photo in gallery (but yes in the storage files), and just now (in the morning) the pic is in the gallery, its like takes half day to show in it the gallery, really idk nothing about this problem, its part of something of u were talking in the first comment or another problem?

Comment: @SumitSahoo hey, i installed api 28 who is for A. v9, now, in my Samsung J7 the pics are saving in the sdcard but not showing in the gallery, any code to refresh it?

Comment: @Kondos sorry for delayed answer, About Gallery part it might be due to Samsung's pathetic software. Gallery actually shows a cached copy of images not the original quality once so that the device doesn't have to word hard on render part. You might try clearing cache of gallery app or use any other pic gallery app from Play Store.

Comment: @SumitSahoo hey, i installed another "Simple gallery" and was the same, until i realized there was an option on that gallery: "Show temporally hide files" i click on that, and bam, the album with my app pics show up, so, whats that? my files are "temporally hiden?" idk how to proceed with that.. can u help me?

Update: i tried the app on a Motorola G2 and the gallery from that smarthphone shows the pics immediately on the gallery, so, back to problem; how i can fix that issue on the samsung? idk how to proced

Comment: because there must be some way, but how does the samsung gallery refresh the images taken from his vanilla camera? the problem is idk how to do that with my app...